# Android Saving Sound as Ringtone - Title not being used in Ringtone List

Tags: java, android, audio, notifications, ringtone

In my code I'm setting a sound file as a ringtone. It mostly works fine.

This issue is that it doesn't use the ContentValue's TITLE entry for the Ringtone name in the ringtone list. In the following code, I set the TITLE key to "Custom Name". But in the ringtone selection list it insists on showing up as "testTone" (The filename is "testTone.mp3").

```
// Take the given file and add it to the ringtone list
private Uri makeRingtone(File soundFile) {
  String path = soundFile.getAbsolutePath();

  // Make sure the system knows about it
  sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
          Uri.parse("file://"+path)));

  // Plug in same important values
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
  values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, path);  
  values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Custom Name");
  values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*"); 
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);  
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);  
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);  
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

  // The ol' delete then insert trick:
  Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(path);
  getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + path + "\"", null);
  Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

  Log.d(TAG, "New Uri: " + newUri);

  return newUri;
}
```

This is similar to the issue: [Saving sounds as ringtones using the title of the sound instead of number location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8172539/1512137)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line and the ringtone will show up with the proper title:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
      Uri.parse("file://"+path)));
```